# Show if f is continuous and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

(Note: Sry guys, i put a wrong function)
Prove, for which $x$ is $f(x)$ 
a) continuous
b)differentiable

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x\sin x , & \mbox{for } x\in Q  \\ 0, & \mbox{else}\end{cases}$

for a)
We know $R\setminus Q$ is   dense  in $R$

That means, for each $x$ element of $Q$  there exist a sequences  $y_n$ element of $R\setminus Q$ such that
 $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=x  $.
$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0\neq f(x) $.

Which proves, that f(x) is not continous for  $x\in Q$.
Analogical we can prove, that $f(x)$ is not continous for  $x\in R\setminus Q$ and $x \neq k\pi$.
This is my first suggestion for a.

Now for the case and $x = k\pi$ and $x\in R\setminus Q$ for those x we can find always a sequences  $y_n$ element of $ Q$ such that
 $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=x  $.
Now for all $x$, $f(x)=0$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0= f(x) $.
Which proves at $x = k\pi$ f is continuous.

b) $x=k\pi$
$$
\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{y_n\sin y_n-0}{y_n -x}\right|=?,
$$
i would use hopital
$$
\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{\sin y_n+y_n\cos y_n}{1}\right|=\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{y_n\cos y_n}{1}\right|=k\pi,
$$

or b)  we use $$|sin(x-k\pi)|=|sin(x)|$$
$$
\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{y_n\sin y_n-0}{y_n -x}\right|=\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{y_n\sin (y_n-k\pi)}{y_n -k\pi}\right|=\left|\lim_{y_n\to x}y_n\lim_{y_n\to x}\frac{\sin (y_n-k\pi)}{y_n -k\pi}\right|=\lim_{y_n\to x}y_n*1=k\pi,
$$

Comment: can someone please check b) ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The only possible number for both continuity and differentiability  is 0.
$$
\left|\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x-0}x\right|=0,
$$
which gives differentiability.

This function is also continuous in points $k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. (It is given by a minor modification of your arguments).

Comment: for 0, let $\lim_{n->\infty }y_n=0$ and $y_n \in Q$. we know $\lim_{n->\infty }f(y_n)=\lim_{n->\infty }(y_n)sin(y_n)=0=f(0)$. which proves f is continuous at 0

Comment: @Beginner Certainly. But differentiability implies continuity. Or are you expected to show a) and b) separately?

Comment: We have to prove a and b independently of each other. Is my argumentation for all other x  ok? or its wrong ?

Comment: @Beginner Oh, I see. This function is also continuous in all point, where $x\sin x=$, i.e. $x=k\pi$.

Comment: true! i edited my post.